# Permitting Joins in SQL when encrypting data with CMEK in Google Cloud Big Query

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dlv9wJheF8&list=PLIivdWyY5sqIij_cgINUHZDMnGjVx3rxi&index=11) GCP engineers show how to encrypt data using a customer provided encryption key. This allows data to be encrypted E2E and the customer can keep the private key securely stored in house.

However, does this still allow joining tables based on certain values in the columns? AFAIK, encryption always adds some randomness to the message and as such, each time a value is encrypted, it will result in a different output while in its encrypted state. As such, joins should not work.

Am I correct in this belief? What are possible mitigations to enable joining despite having encryption? Any personally identifiable information is a common target for encryption, however joins, even on an encrypted value such as the customer ID, are essential for many applications.

Comment: Is your question generic one or you have a specific example which is not working which you can share? Regardless, my understanding is that Since Bigquery tables are always encrypted at rest either by the default key or by client key I don't see any reason you won't be able to join the tables. As @Felipe mentioned in the video "as long as there is access to the key" the table can be query.

Comment: So this means in consequence that if the BigQuery systems do not have access to the key, joins will not work anymore? The purpose of a customer managed key if of course to not give access to the key to Google. So assuming Googles *does* have access to it is sort of misleading.